# RegEx ignore in java

Tags: java, regex

Hi i've got a String like "DE32424;WV424324;FR234324;DE45345"

How would I ignore everything after the first ; so only DE32424 would be left in the string after using .replaceAll() in JAVA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replaceAll(";.*", "");`

Answer (score 1):

`yourString.substring(0, yourString.indexOf(';'))`

Comment: Careful. What if `yourString.indexOf(';')` returns `-1`?

Comment: This option may be faster than regexp. Worth to try.